# Seaborn greyout colors in default palette but one

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am working with pandas and seaborn to create the following plot.
dataframe looks like this:

```
         X         Y      cluster
0   -30.004160  -3.693206   12
1   13.828905   -0.687667   6
2   -25.441136  10.831853   12
3   11.885529   -2.018328   16
4   12.292833   -13.362101  14
```

and this is a pic of my plot with the following code:

`sns.scatterplot(x='X', y='Y', hue='cluster', style='cluster', data=df_opentsne, legend=None)`

[image]

I want to keep the original colors and greyout the rest. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62020588/seaborn-multi-line-plot-with-only-one-line-colored) I found a good approach but not keeping the original colors.

Any ideas? I would like to keep using seaborn for this.

```
palette = {c:'purple' if c==14 else 'darkgrey' for c in df.cluster.unique()}
sns.scatterplot(x='X', y='Y', hue='cluster', style='cluster', data=df_opentsne, legend=None, palette=palette)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get the first pic with your code. What colormap did you use?

Comment: I am using the default color palette in seaborn, defined here  I wanted to look at the color names to create a mapping but I cannot find what colors it is using. https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

Comment: for numeric cluster, I got the points being scaled from black to pink to white. Changing to categorical cluster helps.

Comment: Sorry, yes I stored my cluster as categorical with this code  df['cluster'] = pd.Categorical(model.labels_)